# its about induction and i got a contradiction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

By induction we can show infinite union of finite disjoint set is finite
we prove it by induction
let us take the @ be the family of infinite disjoint finite sets,then we describe elements of @ be of form A1,A2,A3...so on.
then we prove that union of this infinite number of finite disjoint sets to be finite,
we prove it by induction 
for n=1 we see that it is trivially true since we know that set of all @ is a finite set so for n=1 it is true
for n=2 it will be of form $A_1\cup A_2$ and we know that it is also finite it is a theorem and it is proven 
then for n=3 we can take $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3$ and we know that $A1\cup A2$ is finite then again doing union with a finite set will generate another finite set.
thus let us assume it is true until a 'n' belongs to N.
then we prove it is true for n+1
we assumed that $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup ......\cup A_n$ is finite 
then let us take $A_1\cup A_2\cup ......\cup A_n=D$
So $D\cup A_{n+1}$ is finite and we know that.
so the thm is true for all 'n' belongs to $\mathbb N$.
but which we know is false -_-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that at each step of your induction, you are taking the union of $n$ sets. So, you managed to prove by induction that the finite union of finite sets is finite, **NOT** that an infinite union of finite sets is finite.

Comment: didnt i prove it for all natural number?

Comment: @Mukil Yes, all natural numbers. And every natural number is finite.

Comment: ty i understood ^^

Comment: but set of all natural number is not finite

Comment: Yes, but you prove it for each natural number...and each natural number is finite. Whether the natural numbers as a set have finite cardinality or not really doesn't matter.

Comment: dude ben we take all possible singleton sets and union all of them and what we get is infinite set isnt? just a doubt

Comment: Yes...but you have still only proved that it holds for sets which have finite cardinality, so you can't say anything about the union of all possible singleton sets.

Answer (score 1):

Writing what you proved and what you think you proved in a more rigorous mathematical language may help you understand the difference:

You proved:

> If $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots$ is an infinite family of disjoint sets, then, for every $n\in\mathbb N$, the set $$\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$$
>   is finite.

You did claim you proved:

> If $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots$ is an infinite family of disjoint sets, then the set $$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$$
>   is finite.

This second statement cannot be proven by the induction that proves the first statement, because it is a statement that does not contain the $n\in\mathbb N$ over which you can run the induction.

The first statement tells you that no matter how many sets you take the **finite** union of, you will still get a finite set. The second statement would tell you that an infinite union obeys the same rule, which is a different (and, in fact, false) statement alltogether.

Comment: ty i understood